# Correct HTML Link not working (last 7 characters get cut in browser)?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I am programming a chatbot for my universities Moodle Plattform. Everything is working fine except one part:

When I try to access one page in Moodle, the html link is simply not working correctly. The last ID-part simply gets cut when calling the link via my button.

I want this link in my Browser:
"https://hagenberg.elearning.fh-ooe.at/course/view.php?id=7961"

But I always get this one after calling it:
"https://hagenberg.elearning.fh-ooe.at/course/view.php?"

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
let link = props.item.object[2].buttons[0].postback.toString();

if (attachment.type === "card") {

        console.log(link);

        return (
            <div>
                <form action={link} method="get" target="_blank">
                    <button id="linkbutton">Kurs anzeigen!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

When checking the element in the console i get this:

```
<form action="https://hagenberg.elearning.fh-ooe.at/course/view.php?id=7961" 
method="get" target="_blank">
<button id="linkbutton">Kurs anzeigen!</button></form>
```

Therefore the link gets pasted to the button perfectly fine. When I call it from the console (Chrome Dev Tools) it also is working perfectly fine. **Only when I click the button it is not!**

How can I preserve the id part?

I am thankful for any help, as this is the last bit missing for my bachelor thesis until I can hand it in... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not using a link, but a form. The form sends its data via GET, meaning all form content (which is nothing in this case) is put into the url as parameters, overwriting your id.

I'd suggest using an actual link, since the form does not look like it should send data anyway. A link would look like this:

```
<a href="https://hagenberg.elearning.fh-ooe.at/course/view.php?id=7961" target="_blank">Kurs anzeigen!</a>
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: This is the best way to handle your situation but just adding a note in case you would need to go with a form in the future you would just have to strip the id value and create a hidden input with the value and it will be sent with the form.
 <input type="hidden" name='id' value="[value]" />

Comment: @Calimera That's why StackOverflow exists. Good look with your bachelor thesis btw.